# Changing css styles with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are already threads on this but I couldn't find an answer to fit my needs. I'm trying to use external JS to change external CSS. I have a very simple CSS body style:

```
html, body{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
```

To change this with JavaScript I tried:

```
var bg = document.getElementById("body");
body.style.backgroundColor = white;
```

But that didn't seem to work. I don't have too much experience with CSS combined with JavaScript so I think the fix is something simple but I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

Comment: you are using `white`, and javascript takes it as variable, it should be a string. eg. `'white'`.

Answer (score 6):

You have *lots* of problems

1. `var bg = document.getElementById("body");` will get `<something id="body">` not `<body>` (but your CSS is matching `<body>` so presumably that is what you want to change)
2. `body.style.backgroundColor` is using a variable called `body` not `bg` (which is what you used before.
3. `= white` assigns the value of the *variable* `white`, not the string `"white"`.

Corrected code:

```
var bg = document.body;
bg.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Comment: +1 the only other answer to notice the body ID issue, beat me by 11 seconds :)

Comment: Looks like I'm more rusty than I thought. I tried this code, with adding in `bg.style.color = "black";` and the font color changes but not the background.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `white` a string like `"white"`

Javascript is reading `white` as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong variable!

```
var bg = document.getElementById("body");
bg.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Comment: I guess that the OP wants to change the background color of the body (and not of the element with an ID of body)...

Comment: Yes I agree, a lot went wrong here. I would agree with @Quentin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

replace `body.style.backgroundColor = white;` with

```
body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

Here color name must be a string

To change the body back ground color use

```
 document.body.style.background = 'white';
```

Answer (score 0):

Has your `<body>` really got an `id="body"`?

You can select the body with `document.body` and use quotes for the colour value:

```
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

Or a hex colour

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
```

Answer (score 0):

`white` should be enclosed within single or double quotes

no need to use `var bg = document.getElementById("body");` as i dont feel you are using variable `bg` anywhere